# Accessing JSON object in SAPUI5 via xsodata

Tags: javascript, json, odata, sapui5

I try to access the value of my json objects in sap ui5, but the getproperty function cannot access the required data.
But, at first, I have created a xsodata file with some service definitions, e.g.

```
"CUSTOMER_ATTR_G3" as "Customers";
```

Then I try to get these data in view.js file with the following code:

```
oModel.loadData("UserInterface_G3/SERVICES/CUSTOMER_ATTR_G3.xsodata/Customers?$select=CUSTOMER_ID,CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION&$format=json");
```

When I am using console.log(oModel) I see in the odata section that the values are in the object but I cannot access to them. The following screenshot should show the structure of the object:
[image: Object structure]

I tried for instance:

```
console.log(oModel.getProperty('/CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION'));
```

or

```
console.log(oModel.getProperty('results/CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION'));
```

But I cannot access the values of the object.

Does anybody have an idea on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> console.log(oModel.getProperty('results/CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION'));

You need to access your Property like that:

```
console.log(oModel.getProperty('d/results/0/CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION'));
```

You forgot the position inside of your Array. Your Path needs the position, so if you want to get the first entry `CS_0001` then you have to write `result/0/CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION`.

**EDIT:**

Actually it depends on your Model, how you have to access the Property. Can you pls show me how you defined your oModel?

Comment: When I am writing this code: console.log(oModel.getProperty('results/0/CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION')); I got a null value =/.. An optimal case would be if I would get all of the customer descriptions

Comment: The result is: Object {}. I wrote console.log(oModel.getData());

Comment: When I am using: console.log(oModel.oData.getData()); --> I am getting the error code: "Uncaught TypeError: oModel.oData.getData is not a function". When I am using: console.log(oModel.oData); --> Then I am getting the result: Object {}.

Comment: I am instantiating with this model type: var oModel  = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(); After this I use the part with:    oModel.loadData("UserInterface_G3/SERVICES/CUSTOMER_ATTR_G3.xsodata/Customers?$select=CUSTOMER_ID,CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTION&$format=json"). But something like. setData I didnot use